# Python recursive function not recursing

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to solve a puzzle, which is to reverse engineer this code, to get a list of possible passwords, and from those there should be one that 'stands out', and should work

```
function checkPass(password) {
    var total = 0;
    var charlist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
        var countone = password.charAt(i);
        var counttwo = (charlist.indexOf(countone));
        counttwo++;
        total *= 17;
        total += counttwo;
    }
    if (total == 248410397744610) {
        //success//
    } else {...
```

I wrote something in python that I think should work, I reverse engineered the order of which it adds and multiplies, and has it try every character to see if it properly divides into an even number.

```
from random import shuffle

def shuffle_string(word):
    word = list(word)
    shuffle(word)
    return ''.join(word)

charlist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
total = 248410397744610
temp = total
password = ''
runtime = 20

def runlist():
    global charlist
    global total
    global temp
    global password
    global runtime
    for i in range(25):
        if (temp - (i+1))  % 17 == 0:
            password += charlist[i]
            temp -= i+1
            temp = temp /17

    if temp == 0:
        print password
        password = ''
        temp = total
        runtime += 1
        charlist = shuffle_string(charlist)
        if runtime < 21:
            runlist()
    else:
        runlist()
```

But when I try to run it I only get

```
deisx

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm wondering why my function isn't recursing properly, because it looks like it should from what I see. try and run it yourself, and see what happens.

There should be multiple solutions for this puzzle (I think?), and I was planning on making it be able repeat until it gets all solutions, but I'm a little lost on why it just runs through every letter once, then dies.

**EDIT:
Revised code to actually recurse, but now I get no output, and still finish with exit code 0.**

**EDIT 2:
Revised code again to fix a mistake**

Comment: Your function doesn't actually recurse - nowhere does it call itself.

Comment: In Python, indentation is part of syntax. Your recursive call is outside of function body,

Comment: The part from `if temp > 0:` is not indented, is that intentional or did it slip by mistake when you edited the question?

Comment: Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid I don't know much about python, but I can probably help you with the algorithm.

The encoding process repeats the following:

- multiply the current total by 17
- add a value (a = 1, b = 2, ..., z = 26) for the next letter to the
  total

So at any point, the total is a multiple of 17 plus the value of the final letter. So each step in the recursive solver must remove the final letter then divide the result by 17.

However, because the multiplier is 17 and there are 26 characters in the alphabet, some of the remainder values may be produced by more than one letter - this is where many passwords may give rise to the same solution.

For example:

- encoding "a" gives a total of 1, and 1 % 17 = 1
- encoding "r" gives a total of 18, and 18 % 17 = 1

So if the current remainder is 1, then the encoded letter may be either "a" or "r". I think in your solution you only ever look for the first of these cases, and miss the second.

In pseudo code, my function to solve this would look something like:

```
function decodePassword(total, password)
    if total == 0
        print password
        return
    end if

    var rem = total / 17       # integer division - truncate
    var char1 = total % 17     # potential first character
    var char2 = char1 + 17     # potential second character

    # char1 values 1-16 map to letters a-p
    if char1 >= 1
        decodePassword(rem, charlist.charAt(char1 - 1) + password)
    end if

    # char2 values 17-26 map to letters q-z
    if rem > 0 && char2 <= 26
        decodePassword(rem - 1, charlist.charAt(char2 - 1) + password)
    end if

end function
```

If it helps, the answer you are looking for is 12 chars long, and probably not printable in this forum!

HTH

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot, your explanation helped me think about the problem in a way that made a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is neither repeating nor recursing because:

1. The `runlist` function is only called once
2. The `runlist` function does not fit the pattern for recursion which is:

   - Check for end of processing condition and if met return final result
   - Otherwise return the results so far plus of calling youself